# How to return a value from within activedirectory method

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory

I've got a method in a class which does query an ActiveDirectory.
Therefore I'm using 'activedirectory2' npm package.
I successfully authenticated and successfully logged my result to console.

Now that I have instanciated my class and have tried to call the method, I'm not abled to get a non-empty result.

I tried it with getters/setters to make the _result value available after instaciating the class.
I tried to solve my issue with research on asynchronous calls, but obviously wasn't able to ask the right question.

class Activedirectory

```
var ActiveDirectory = require("activedirectory2");

class AuthenticateWithLDAP {
   constructor(user, password){
     this._result = [];
     this.user = user;
     this.password = password;
     this.config = {
        url: "ldaps://someldap",
        baseDN: "somebasdn",
        username: this.user,
        password: this.password,
        filter: 'somefilter',
     }
     this.ad = new ActiveDirectory(this.config);
   }
   //Auth Method
   auth() {
     var result = this._result;
     this.config.entryParser = function(entry,raw,callback){
       if(entry.hasOwnProperty('info')) {
        result.push(entry.info);
        this._result = result;
      } 
      callback(entry);
     }
     this.ad.authenticate(config.username, config.password, (err,auth)=>{
      if (err) {
        //some error handling
      }
      if (auth) {
        this.ad.find(config,async (err, userDetails) => {
          var result = this._result;
          {
            if (err) {
              //some error handling
            }
            if(!userDetails) {
              console.log("No users found.");
            } else {
              this._result = result[0]; //I want this result!
              console.log('result: ', this._result); 
              return await this._result;
            }
          }
        })
      } else {
        console.log("Authentication failed!");
      }
    });
   }
//getter/setter
  get result(){
    return this._result;
  }
  set result(value) {
    this._result.push(value);
  }
}
module.exports = AuthenticateWithLDAP;
```

route module

```
const express = require('express');
const AuthwithLDAP = require('AuthenticateWithLDAP');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req,res,next) => {
   let x = async ()=> {
        authwithldap = new AuthwithLDAP(req.body.user,req.body.password);
        return await authwithldap.auth();
    }
    x().then((res)=>{
      console.log('res: ', res); //always []
    })
})
```

I expected to be able to use the _result value of AuthenticateWithLDAP class in my router.post method handler.
Actually i only get [] (empty array) in router.post.

Could you please tell me how to alter the value _result in a way, so that the instance of the class knows it and can use it outside the class itself.

Thank you very much.

Micha

Comment: Did you mean to write `return await authwithldap.auth();` instead of `return await authwithldap;`?

Comment: thanks for the hint Wendelin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but I think this should work.
In your code you cant return the result because the return is in a callback.
There are to ways to fix that.

1. Pass a callback to the `auth()` method (This is bad since callbacks suck)
2. Return a promise and that resolves to the result

I've decided to go for promises.

```
var ActiveDirectory = require("activedirectory2");

class AuthenticateWithLDAP {
   constructor(user, password){
     this._result = [];
     this.user = user;
     this.password = password;
     this.config = {
        url: "ldaps://someldap",
        baseDN: "somebasdn",
        username: this.user,
        password: this.password,
        filter: 'somefilter',
     }
     this.ad = new ActiveDirectory(this.config);
   }
   //Auth Method
   auth() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       this.ad.authenticate(config.username, config.password, (err,auth)=>{
         if (err) {
           //Call reject here
         }
         if (auth) {
           this.ad.find(config,async (err, userDetails) => {
             var result = this._result;
             {
               if (err) {
                 //some error handling
               }
               if(!userDetails) {
                 console.log("No users found.");
               } else {
                 this._result = result[0]; //I want this result!
                 resolve(await this._result);
               }
             }
          })
         } else {
           console.log("Authentication failed!");
         }
       });
     });
   }
}
module.exports = AuthenticateWithLDAP;
```

```
const express = require('express');
const AuthwithLDAP = require('AuthenticateWithLDAP');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req,res,next) => {
   /* This code can be simplifed
    let x = async () => {
        authwithldap = new AuthwithLDAP(req.body.user,req.body.password);
        return await authwithldap.auth();
    }
    x().then((res)=>{
      console.log('res: ', res); //always []
    })
   */
  (async () => {
     authwithldap = new AuthwithLDAP(req.body.user,req.body.password);
     var res = await authwithldap.auth();
     console.log('res: ', res);
  })();
})
```

Comment: You made my day. That's the solution. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Always a pleasure to help! But please mark this as the correct answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add syntax "await" like this?

```
await x().then((res)=>{
  console.log('res: ', res); //always []
})
```

As your "x" method is in async mode, maybe you have to wait for the Promise to be resolved...